# How to dowload an excel file from backend in frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, xlsx, js-xlsx

I want to launch a browser download of an excel file generated in my backend, but I can't figure how to pass that kind of response.

```
app.get('/all', function (req, res) {
    db.query(...) LIMIT 20000;")
    .then(function (data) {
        let result = []
        data.forEach(element => {
            result.push(element)
        })

        /* make the worksheet */
        var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);

        /* add to workbook */
        var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "All");

        XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'alltest1.xlsx'); //This saves the file in my server but I don't know how to send it as a response.

        console.log('Ready');

        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR:", error)
    })
})
```

I have been trying to create the excel in the frontend but chrome runs out of memory due to the big amount of data I think. I have also try to pass a buffer but the file I was getting seems to be corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the response header **[Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)** and [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) of the file which tells the browser that file is send as response

```
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition',
        "attachment; filename='alltest1'; filename*=UTF-8\'\'alltest1.xlsx");
res.setHeader('Content-Type', "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

and send the file content as response

```
res.send(wb)
```

**OR** you can also use [res.download](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download).

```
res.download(filePath, fileName, (err) => { if (err) console.log(err); })
```

Comment: And this should launch a download in my browser?

Comment: Have you try this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I still don't getting the file.

Comment: What are you getting in response

Comment: `const response = await fetch(url, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
  const res = await response.json()
  console.log(res)` this is the code in the front and this is the console.log `{SheetNames: Array(1), Sheets: {…}}`

Comment: @ODLana I have updated my code. give it a try and let me know, if this works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks, with that and some tweaks in my front I managed to solve the problem.